# Edit another user profile using FOSUser Bundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm working with Symfony and FOSUser Bundle, and I'm learning. I got a problem, I need to be able to show and edit all the users registered using FOSUser Bundle. I can show the list of every users but when i tried to edit them with fos_user_profile_edit I only able to edit my account no the rest of the users. Here is my Controller code:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homeProfesionales")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $users = $userManager->findUsers();

        return $this->render('GOCProfesionalesBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('users' =>   $users));

}

/**
 * @Route("/show", name="showProfesionales")
 */
public function showAction($id)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('FOSUserBundle:User')->find($id);

    return $this->render('GOCProfesionalesBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('entity'=> $entity));
}

/**
 * @Route("/edit", name="editProfesionales")
 */
public function editAction($user)
{
    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $user = $userManager->findUsers();

    return $this->render('GOCProfesionalesBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('users' =>   $users));
}

}
```

and in my view I just call them :

```
{% for user in users %}
  {{ user.username}}
  {{ user.email }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

`FosUserBundle` intended to provide registration/authentication and profile functionality, not admin one.

Looks like you want to implement administration backend on your site to edit various entities. There are 2 third-party bundles which can help you implement it:

1. [EasyAdminBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/installation.html)
2. [SonataAdminBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/index.html)

Both bundles provide integration with `FosUserBundle`. Personally, I think `EasyAdminBundle` is easier to use and more attracted to Symfony beginners, and `SonataAdminBundle` provides more functionality.

Take a look at the Sonata demo application: https://demo.sonata-project.org/ (Click on `admin` menu items to get to admin section after demo application is loaded)

Comment: Hello @VadimAshikhman thanks! but the thing is that I only need the function to edit, is there any solution without those AdminBundles?

Comment: Sure, create custom edit page where you implememt form and persistence logic. You can read more about form creation and entity peraistence in the Symfony documentation